# Can I safely call an asynchronous function at the end of a synchronous function?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I can't seem to find a straightforward answer to this one, as almost every resource inverts my question to "Can I call synchronous from within Asynchronous". I'm also asking out of curiosity and with the intention of understanding the relationship between sync and async.

Below is a very basic example of what I was thinking, but I've previously worked with some asynchronous and synchronous elements poorly in the past and want to follow a best practice.

These are all functions I know can safely run first, as most of them are html setups based on a few system details such as date and time.

```js
// Fires from body's onload
function startup(){
   // Begin startup and setup
   makeDivs();
   getDate();
   setUpInputHandlers();
   
   
   // Begin API and Async functions
   startupAsync();
}

async function startupAsync(){
   await callApi();
   await doDataWork();
   // more async functions throughout.
}
```

I'm *not* looking to do anything synchronous with the async data, but I want a few processes to run before I jump onto my API calls and work with API data. Would something akin to the above be a safe way to do this? I know it would be easier to make both startups async.

Comment: short answer: **Yes, it's perfectly fine.** *"... the intention of understanding ..."* async/await is just syntactic sugar on top of Promises, like JS' `class` is syntactic sugar on top of its prototype based inheritance system. If you want to understand the working of `async/await` take a look into Promises. `async/await` just "hides" all the `.then((arg) => { ... })`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want `startup()` to execute the async functions `callApi()` and `doDataWork()` before doing something else, then startup should be an async function too.

```js
async function startup(){
   makeDivs();
   getDate();
   setUpInputHandlers();
   await callApi();
   await doDataWork();
}

await startup()
// then do something afer the async functions finish
```

If you want to do something else while the async functions run, then startup does not need to be an async function.

```js
function startup(){
   makeDivs();
   getDate();
   setUpInputHandlers();
   (async function(){
     await callApi();
     await doDataWork();
   })();
}

startup()
// do something while async operations run
```